# angularJs and ocLazyLoader

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, laravel-5

I'm pretty new with angularJs. Currently I'm developing a one-page website with laravel framework.

Currently I have only one ngView, where i put my home page codes, but the issues is that all components like sliders, gallery is not working when i put them in a view file. After some searches I found out a module called ocLazyLoad. Modules are loading but sometimes other scripts are loading before jQuery and website again doesn't display the components.

Is there any way to force Loader or Angular to load scripts first and then display view ?

```
.run(function($rootScope, $state, $ocLazyLoad) {



            $ocLazyLoad.load({

                name: 'authApp',

                files: ['style/js/jquery.min.js', 
                'style/js/bootstrap.min.js',
                'style/js/googlemap.js',
                'style/js/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js',
                'style/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js',
                'style/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js',
                'style/js/jquery.easytabs.min.js',
                'style/js/owl.carousel.min.js',
                'style/js/jquery.isotope.min.js',
                'style/js/jquery.fitvids.js',
                'style/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js',
                'style/js/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.2',
                'style/js/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.0',
                'style/js/jquery.slickforms.js',
                'style/js/instafeed.min.js',
                'style/js/retina.js',
                'style/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js',
                'style/js/scripts.js']

            });
```

I'm loading everything in module.run() function.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [RequireJs](http://requirejs.org/) instead of ocLazyLoader for this kind of problems.

RequireJs allows you to choose which library has to be loaded first according to its own dependency.

For example if you are using a jQuery plugin you know that it will needs jQuery to work properly, so you will load this plugin with jQuery as a dependency and RequireJs will load everything in the right order.